# How many three-digit odd numbers are there with no repeated digits?

Tags: combinatorics

I know the answer is $5\cdot 8\cdot 8 = 320.$ My question is why did we go from last digit to first digit to middle digit instead of last-middle-first ? What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: Which digit is more informative/restrictive?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The last digit is the most informative and the first digit is the most restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't do it going last-middle-first. The [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) only works when the number of options at each step is exactly the same regardless - but if we chose the middle number first, then depending on whether the middle digit was a $0$ or not, we'd get a potentially different number of possibilities for the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

You must select digits for the units, tens, and hundreds column, where the units' digit *must be one from the five odd digits*, the hundreds' digit *may not be zero* **or** the same as the units', and the tens' digit must be different from both.

So we find it easier to count ways to select in order of: the units, the hundreds, and the tens.$$5\cdot 8\cdot 8$$

---

When selecting in order of units, tens, then hundreds, it is a just little more complicated.

We would count: ways to select one from five odd digits for units, then *either* select "0" for the tens and one from the eight remaining digits for the hundreds, *or else* select one from eight non-zero digits for tens and one from the seven remaining non-zero digits for hundreds. $$5\cdot(1\cdot 8+8\cdot 7)$$